# Javascript comparison with an empty array and booleans

Tags: javascript

As you can see in [this javascript equality table](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/), javascript equality transitivity is weird.

I understand most of the results of the table, but I have a question regarding the following comparison:

```
[] == true // false
[] == false // true
!![] == true // true
!![] == false // false
```

But also:

```
if ([]) {
    // this code will run
}

if (!![]) {
    // and of course this too
}
```

Why? Is this another extremly bad part? Have this a reasonable explanation?

Comment: @Tomalak: I dare you to run `[] == false` in your console :-P

Comment: When using `==`, it needs to convert both operands to the same type.  So what it does is converts `[]` to a string (`''`) and then to a number (`0`).  It then converts `false` to a number (`0`), then compares them.  I'm still trying to figure out why `!![]` is true when `[] == false` is also true.

Comment: Look into Truthy and Falsy comparisons http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: You're forgetting that JavaScript is dynamically typed : `!![] == []` is false. Please use `===` or `length`, `typeof foo === "undefined"`.

Comment: The fun part of this question (and JavaScript's stupid truth table) is that `(!![]) === ([] == false)` is true :)

Comment: look up the terms "type coercion"

Comment: @honyovk your link says nothing about my question :(

Comment: typeof NaN .... what do you think?